# Version does not change using Phonegap Build API

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I use Phonegap Build API to build my app.

I compress my app's source code as a .zip archive including a config.xml file which contains several features and "version" and "versionCode" -for Android-. Anyway, I did everything right in the config.xml file. The problem is that, when I change the version and versionCode and then send the source code archive file -config.xml is also in the archive- back to Phonegap Build, my app's version does not change.

When I download the .apk file generated by Phonegap Build, the app seems to be unchanged. I don't see the recent changes I did in the app. Even if I uninstall the app and rebuild it and then download and install again, it still remains the same old app.

What should I do? Should I upload .zip and config.xml files separately for updates to be processed correctly?

Comment: If you get the old version, even if you uninstall first, PhoneGap Build didn't build a new one. Double check if you uploaded a new ZIP.
And check the detail infos of your app:
For instance…
Version: 0.3.4, Last built (509) 1 minute
Those values should be changing when you upload a new version.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I'm having the same issue...

Comment: @BenDrury I don't remember how and why the issue was resolved and never occured again. Both Phonegap and Phonegap Build teams were frequently updating things and fixing bugs those day. I wish I could help you. Can you give more details? By the way, don't forget to ask for help about your issue on the [community support page](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi)

Comment: It actually resolved the next day and hasn't reoccurred.  Can't help with what the issue was. Another coding anomaly never to be solved!